# Gradle list local project dependencies

Tags: gradle, dependencies

I have the following project structure:

```
root
- A
- B
    - B1
    - B2
- C
```

with B1 depending on B2 and A. B2 also depends on A and on C. All of these projects have also external dependencies that are downloaded from a central repository.

Is there a gradle task to get all local dependencies (transitive)? I want to some kind of

```
B1
- A
- B2
  - A
  - C
```

preferably flat and without duplicates. The project itself might be omitted as well, that is not important. **Note: No dependencies from central repositories are shown**

Does such a task exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gradle has several ways of inspecting dependencies, but I don't think any of it has a filter that restricts it to only "project" dependencies. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:listing_dependencies

Also note that a project has different dependency configurations where each configuration has its own set of dependencies.

So you need to talk for example about showing all "compile" dependencies of a project.

However one of the big advantages of gradle is that it is easily scriptable with groovy.

This quick draft works for me to show all dependencies in "compile" configuration.
Just add it to the root project and invoke "gradlew projectDependencies".
This has been tested in exactly one example project (in other words "mostly untested") and is not very flexible ("compile" configuration is hardcoded).
However I tried to make it understandable by using explicit types and multiple lines, so that you can extend it:

```
task projectDependencies {
    doLast {
        showProjectDependencies(rootProject, 0)
    }
}

def showProjectDependencies(Project project, int nesting) {
    ConfigurationContainer configurations = project.configurations
    Configuration configuration = configurations.compile
    println " " * (3 * nesting) + project.name
    DomainObjectSet<ProjectDependency> projectDependencies = configuration.dependencies.withType ProjectDependency
    projectDependencies.forEach {
        showProjectDependencies(it.dependencyProject, nesting + 1)
    }
}
```