# Determine local module gradle dependencies

Tags: gradle

I have a multi module/project setup. I want to get a listing of only the local modules that the main project depends on, rather than every dependency.

So:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':foo')
    implementation project(':bar')
    implementation project(':baz')
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:${daggerVersion}"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:${daggerVersion}"
}
```

The local projects also have other dependencies on local projects.

The `gradle dependencies` command produces a tree of every dependency, but I only want the local ones (`project('*')`)

The end goal is to determine which modules were changed in a PR and then run unit tests only in those modules. However, if module foo did not have any changes but it imports another module that did change, then unit tests for module foo need to be run as well. I am not sure how to determine this local DAG.

Is there some command(s) that I can leverage?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54759663/gradle-list-local-project-dependencies